# Asp.Net Form Textbox

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, textbox, vs-web-site-project

Hello I have to make a form in Asp.net, Framework 4.0 with VS 2010. 
The Form will have 3 Sites, Start, Input and Control. 
Now i have a little Problem. 
When I make a Input at the Textboxes on the Input Site and go to the Control Site and back, then I can Change the Text of the Textboxes, but the Text wont be changed in the session.item. 
I have done it so.
Textbox.text -> session.item
session.item -> label.text (works)

But when i go back the Text of the session.item doesent change.

Please give me a hint why it does not work.

Comment: I'm not super clear on your question, are you trying to save the contents of the Textbox to a session variable and it's not cooperating?

Comment: Post some code so we can understand your question better cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're trying to change a session variable after it's set when you change text in a textbox? If that's correct, you should just be able to use the TextChanged event in the textbox to reset the session variable when the TextBox is edited.

Try something like this, linked up to the TextChanged event in the textbox

```
protected void TextBoxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Text"] = textbox.Text;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this as it would require autopostback on the textbox, meaning the browser would be posting to the server with every character typed in. However, it would work.

Comment: Yeah, fair point. But I wasn't totally sure what the asker was looking for. Alternately, if there's a button that's supposed to save the TextBox content to the session variable or something, and it isn't working properly we'd probably have to see code to say why.